# Redirecting A Subdirectory and Cleaning the URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

So, this is somewhat of a strange situation. I'm hosting a development server for a person I'm working with in a subfolder of my website. Basically the file structure looks like this:

public_html/my_subfolder/public/index.php

So what I'm attempting to do is make it so that if a user types "www.mysite.com/my_subfolder" they are taken to the "public/index.php" page without the public subfolder appearing in the URL. It's kind of silly that I'm still messing with this, considering it's only a development server.

I'm just at the point where I've messed with it for so long I really want to get it to work now, so that, if nothing else, I'll learn something. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subfolder/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^my_subfolder/(.*)$ /my_subfolder/public/$1 [L,NC]
```

This will redirect everything so make sure to serve your static files like js, css, images etc from `my_subfolder/public` as well.

Comment: Thanks! Do I put this in the .htaccess file in my_subfolder or public_html?

Comment: That should go into .htaccess file in `public_html` folder.

Answer (score 0):

try using the P flag

```
RewriteRule ^/foo(.*) http://bar$1 [P]
```

Thanks

S